# Regex : get an optional parameter, probably sthg simple

Tags: php, html, regex, redirect, nginx

I wondered if it was possible to get an optional parameter from a regex. Here is the regex I tried :

```
rewrite ^/(m/)?string$ /page.php?p=$1
```

The parameter 'm/' is optional, but I would like that if this parameter exist, then p="m" and not the string "m/".

In other words :

```
/m/string  =>  /page.php?p=m
/string    =>  /page.php
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

If you can't solve something by one regex.. Use two regexes!

```
rewrite ^/m/string$ /page.php?p=$1 last;
rewrite ^/string$ /page.php last;
```

The `last` stops further matches of the original URL.

Comment: thank you, it's what I did before but I've many rewrite rules and I would like to simplify..

Comment: @Julien There is no way around using 2 regexes.